# Updating less number of rows than in the query in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a query which gives the minimum effective start date from `xx_name` table and minimum effective_start_date from `xx_ppl` table (By minimum we mean the first row of the table for each person) by comparing these two and in case these dates are different I am updating the name table's first/minimum effective start date with the ppl's first / minimum effective start date.
For this i have created the below cursor :

```
CURSOR cur_p_name
      IS
         SELECT   effective_start_date_name, effective_start_date, person_id
             FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MIN
                                      (x.effective_start_date
                                      ) OVER (PARTITION BY x.person_id)
                                                    effective_start_date_name,
                                   MIN
                                      (y.effective_start_date
                                      ) OVER (PARTITION BY y.person_id)
                                                         effective_start_date,
                                   x.person_id
                              FROM XX_NAME x,
                                   XX_PPL y
                             WHERE x.person_id = y.person_id
--AND X.PERSON_ID='34437'
                  )
            WHERE effective_start_date_name <> effective_start_date
         ORDER BY person_id;
```

Though this is giving me the start_dates which are not equal but when i am using this cursor to update the xx_name table's start date less no. of rows are getting updated.

Is the cursor query incorrect ?

```
Update procedure :

PROCEDURE update_person_date
       IS
          l_count_name           NUMBER;
          l_count_citizenship    NUMBER;
          l_count_visa           NUMBER;
          l_count_leg_data       NUMBER;
          l_count                NUMBER;

          CURSOR cur_p_name
      IS
         SELECT   effective_start_date_name, effective_start_date, person_id
             FROM (SELECT DISTINCT MIN
                                      (x.effective_start_date
                                      ) OVER (PARTITION BY x.person_id)
                                                    effective_start_date_name,
                                   MIN
                                      (y.effective_start_date
                                      ) OVER (PARTITION BY y.person_id)
                                                         effective_start_date,
                                   x.person_id
                              FROM XX_NAME x,
                                   XX_PPL y
                             WHERE x.person_id = y.person_id
--AND X.PERSON_ID='34437'
                  )
            WHERE effective_start_date_name <> effective_start_date
         ORDER BY person_id;


      l_start_date_name      DATE;
      l_start_date_1         DATE;
      l_start_date_citizen   DATE;
      l_start_date_2         DATE;

      num_total_rows  Number :=0;
      num_total_rows_name Number :=0;      


   BEGIN
--person name
      BEGIN
         l_count := 0;

         FOR employee_rec IN cur_p_name
         LOOP
            l_start_date_name := employee_rec.effective_start_date_name;
            l_start_date_1 := employee_rec.effective_start_date;
            l_person_id := employee_rec.person_id;
            num_total_rows_name :=cur_p_name%ROWCOUNT;

            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Total Count updated NAME: ' || num_total_rows_name);


            BEGIN
               UPDATE XX_NAME
                  SET effective_start_date = l_start_date_1
                WHERE effective_start_date = l_start_date_name
                  AND person_id = l_person_id;

                  commit;

                   EXIT WHEN cur_p_name%NOTFOUND;
            EXCEPTION
               WHEN OTHERS
               THEN
                  fnd_file.put_line
                     (fnd_file.LOG,
                         'Exception in updating person name effective start date-Update Block'
                      || l_person_id
                      || ' - '
                      || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 230)
                     );
            END;

            COMMIT;
            l_count := l_count + 1;
         END LOOP;

         DELETE FROM XX_NAME
               WHERE effective_end_date < effective_start_date;



         COMMIT;
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Total Count updated LEG: ' || l_count_leg_data);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS
         THEN
            fnd_file.put_line
                  (fnd_file.LOG,
                      'Exception in updating person LEG effective start date'
                   || l_person_id
                   || ' - '
                   || SUBSTR (SQLERRM, 1, 230)
                  );
      END;

      COMMIT;
   END;
```

Comment: If you are getting the right number of rows, then the problem is the update  .... but you dont show it.

Comment: Hi @JuanCarlosOropeza - I have updated my question

Comment: And what is the difference in the number of rows updated?

Comment: for example i execute the procedure once. 20 rows are left in the table unupdated. When i execute the procedure again then these 20 are also getting updated

Comment: Can you show us sample data / current and expected output?

Comment: You don't appear to be outputting `l_count`, which is the only variable which holds the number of updated records...